# low training score in MLPClassifier (and other classifiers) of scikit

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

(Update: [Posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45152761/1361529) final findings as a separate answer)

I am getting started with trying to understand how to use scikit models for training. I've experimented with well known datasets like iris, MNIST etc - they are all well structured data, ready to be used. This is the first time I am trying to build a model out of raw data on my own and the results are less than desirable.

The data I chose to use is [NHSTA's crash data](https://data.ny.gov/Transportation/Motor-Vehicle-Crashes-Vehicle-Information-Three-Ye/xe9x-a24f) for the last 3 years.

Here is a snapshot of the data, to give you an idea of the fields without having to download the data.

[image: Snapshot of crash data columns]

My first experiment is simple - try and build a model that given "License State Code" and "Age", try and predict the gender (M or F).

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import learning_curve
from sklearn.model_selection import ShuffleSplit
import tensorflow.contrib.learn as skflow
from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators import run_config
from sklearn.svm import SVC
import pickle, seaborn


def plot_learning_curve(estimator, title, X, y, ylim=None, cv=None,
                        n_jobs=1, train_sizes=np.linspace(.1, 1.0, 5)):
    #http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_learning_curve.html
    plt.figure()
    plt.title(title)
    if ylim is not None:
        plt.ylim(*ylim)
    plt.xlabel("Training examples")
    plt.ylabel("Score")
    train_sizes, train_scores, test_scores = learning_curve(
        estimator, X, y, cv=cv, n_jobs=n_jobs, train_sizes=train_sizes)
    train_scores_mean = np.mean(train_scores, axis=1)
    train_scores_std = np.std(train_scores, axis=1)
    test_scores_mean = np.mean(test_scores, axis=1)
    test_scores_std = np.std(test_scores, axis=1)
    plt.grid()

    plt.fill_between(train_sizes, train_scores_mean - train_scores_std,
                     train_scores_mean + train_scores_std, alpha=0.1,
                     color="r")
    plt.fill_between(train_sizes, test_scores_mean - test_scores_std,
                     test_scores_mean + test_scores_std, alpha=0.1, color="g")
    plt.plot(train_sizes, train_scores_mean, 'o-', color="r",
             label="Training score")
    plt.plot(train_sizes, test_scores_mean, 'o-', color="g",
             label="Cross-validation score")

    plt.legend(loc="best")
    plt.show()

#MAIN

crashes = pd.read_csv("crashes.csv", nrows=100000)

# drop useless cols

crashes.drop(["Year","Case Individual ID", "Case Vehicle ID", "Transported    
By", "Injury Location", "Role Type"],axis=1, inplace=True)

crashes = crashes [pd.notnull(crashes['Age'])]
crashes = crashes[crashes.Age >= 10 ] # There are ages < 10 - likely junk data. I don't think they drive


# lets drop rows that are empty
crashes = crashes [pd.notnull(crashes['License State Code'])]
crashes = crashes [pd.notnull(crashes['Injury Severity'])]
crashes = crashes [pd.notnull(crashes['Safety Equipment'])]
crashes = crashes [pd.notnull(crashes['Sex'])]

# converts text fields to numerical values
le = LabelEncoder()
crashes = crashes[crashes.columns[:]].apply(le.fit_transform)
crashes = crashes._get_numeric_data()

# lets plot a heat map to show correlation
corr = crashes.corr()
ax = seaborn.heatmap (corr, xticklabels=corr.columns.values,    
yticklabels=corr.columns.values, annot=True)
plt.setp( ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation=45 )
plt.setp( ax.yaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation=-45 )
plt.show()

crashes_train, crashes_test = train_test_split(crashes, test_size = 0.2)
Y_train = crashes_train['Sex']
X_train =  crashes_train[[ 'Age',  'License State Code']]
Y_test = crashes_test['Sex']
X_test =  crashes_test[[ 'Age', 'License State Code']]


names_train  = crashes_train.columns.values

print "train size ",len (X_train)
print "test size",len (X_test)
#
# cls = RandomForestClassifier(verbose = True)
#
cls = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(10,10,10), max_iter=500, alpha=1e-4,
                  solver='sgd', verbose=10, tol=1e-4, random_state=1,
                  learning_rate_init=0.01)

#cls = tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feats, 
#                                               hidden_units=[50, 50, 50], 
#                                              n_classes=3)

#
#

#cls = SVC(verbose = True)

print "Fitting..."
cls.fit(X_train, Y_train)

plot_learning_curve(cls,"Crash Learning", X_train, Y_train)


print("Training set score: %f" % cls.score(X_train, Y_train))
print("Test set score: %f" % cls.score(X_test, Y_test))
```

I've tried multiple models (from RandomForest, to SVC to MLP etc) - they all come up with a training score of approx 0.56 and a loss of 0.6x

Finally, here is the plot that is being generated for MLP in the current config:
[image]

Here is the plot when I switch to RandomForest. [image]

It looks like the score *decreases* in RandomForest, but overall it ends similar to MLP. What am I doing wrong and how do I improve this approach? Thanks

**Edit**: Based on both answers below, I did a heat map of the correlation between all columns (after dropping the obviously useless ones) - thats pretty bad, but is this the right approach? I could do a PCA as well, but if the basic inter-field correlation is so poor, does it indicate the dataset is largely useless to mine for predictions?

[image: heatmap vis <code>df.corr</code>]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My first experiment is simple - try and build a model that given
>   "License State Code" and "Age", try and predict the gender (M or F).

Well, it is not that simple. You can't simply take any data and try to predict something. The data needs, at least, to be correlated.

A few good things to do:

- Plot the data. Plot these 3 variables (age vs sex, license state code vs sex) and look if they have some correlation.
- Calculate the correlation between the variables, like [Person's Correlation Coefficient](http://learntech.uwe.ac.uk/da/Default.aspx?pageid=1442).
- Use all features you have and the RandomForest/DecisionTree classifier, they have an attribute called `feature_importances_`. This attributes tells you which features are the most important in your data set (accordingly to the model of course)
  The feature importances (the higher, the more important the feature).
- Read more about how MLP and classifiers in general work.

A classification algorithm simply maps input data to a category. However, if there is no relation at all between your input and output this task in unfeasible. Feature selection is a very important area in machine learning. From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_selection):

> In machine learning and statistics, feature selection, also known as variable selection, attribute selection or variable subset selection, is the process of selecting a subset of relevant features (variables, predictors) for use in model construction.

Comment: Thanks - I added a direct column correlation to my question above. I haven't done a PCA yet - is it worth it to work on this dataset if the basic correlation is so low?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the model, it's the data. 'Age' and "License State Code' aren't the best parameters to determine 'Sex' .

Try using the same models for predicting 'Injury Severity' with 'Safety Equipment' and you should get better results.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, the use of safety equipment will have a direct impact in severity, I agree (the training score does go to 0.7x so its an improvement, though not > 0.9) - but its a direct correlation. I am also surprised why its not higher - which makes me think something in my code is wrong .

Comment: It's a direct correlation but not completely correlated E.g 'Airbags deployed' might not always have 'moderate injury' (which is why you are modelling using probabilities instead of writing if-else type conditions).

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to thank @gnobre and @Giantrun to point me to the right direction. I did not want to give up on my end goal of trying to see if I could get a pattern to predict 'Sex' (Gender) from any other column and also be able to better correlate my cross validation and test/train graphs.

First off, I ran a simple correlation between all columns and the results seemed very bad. I wasn't sure if I was working with the right data set in the first place.

[image]

I then decided to use RFE to rank the most important features assuming 'Sex' was the desired prediction. That gave me a set of features - and I took all the True values (1 in rank) as my feature set. That gave me the following training (and test) graph:

[image: heat map]

The overall training score was still low **(0.58)**, but the correlation between training and cross validation was good, which meant I chose the right features, but my goal of predicting 'Sex' was probably not a good one given this data, to begin with. I probably could have kept playing with the MLP layers etc, but I doubt I'd be able to go from 0.5x to 0.9x

My next level of interest was to predict 'Injury Severity', so I changed the Y goal and ran RFE again, which gave me another set of features to pick from. Specifically, these were the columns that came out with a Rank=1 for `Injury Severity`

`['Victim Status',  'Ejection', 'Injury Descriptor', 'Sex']`

Using the resultant fields as features got me much higher training and validation scores **(0.98)** and graphs as such:

[image]

[image]

One conclusion I've drawn is a direct correlation graph is much less useful than doing an RFE or a PCA (correct?)

An open question: What other gotchas can I face in this particular example, when I've managed to get a high test and training score?